# How to Programmatically Eject a Drive for Immutable Backups with Physical Connection?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, backup, external-hard-drive

We are looking for a practical and cost-effective way to enhance the security of our backups.  Our initial idea was to go for immutable backups but unfortunately, due to cost constraints, we are unable to explore hardware solutions.
We are now looking at ensuring immutability through USB Drives for backup and I am seeking a solution for programmatically ejecting a USB drive while still maintaining a physical connection and also mount it back to read its contents. The ejection behavior here needs to be similar to ejecting from Windows Explorer (‘This PC’), as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image]

We want to ensure that even if the USB drive is physically connected to another PC for backups, it remains inaccessible to anyone without the proper authorization.

As per our research we have found the ‘diskpart’ command maybe used to eject the drive programmatically.

```
 Diskpart> list volume
 Diskpart>Select volume 3
 Diskpart>Remove dismount
 Exit
```

Once we re-mount we have found that even though the ‘Volume Label’ will be shown, the contents of the USB drive will not be accessible.

Is there any way the above method of ejecting a remotely -connected USB drive be done programmatically?